# Discord bot won't log messages

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Currently new to coding Discord bots, and was following along with an online tutorial.

I'm stuck on trying to get the client's message method to log the message that the user typed.

Here's my code:

```
  require('dotenv').config(); 
  const Discord = require('discord.js');
  const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILD_MESSAGES"] });
  client.on('ready', () => {
     console.log(`${client.user.tag} has logged in`);
  });

 client.on('message', (msg) => {
    console.log(msg.content);
 });

 client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

The tutorial is a bit outdated since Discordjs has been updated, and I'm not sure if the problem has to do with the intent or something else.

The bot is able to login to the server and shows up as online, with the console registering the login.

However, the console is never able to log any messages sent. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Message contents will be deprecated if you not really need them. A post by discord about this: https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/4404772028055-Message-Content-Access-Deprecation-for-Verified-Bots
You're still able to get the message if your bot got mentioned. Otherwise consider using commands.

The answer made a correct response, my point still stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include both intents:

```
intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES]
```

You can still use `client.on('message')` but it will come with a `DEPRACATED` warning, so as of v13 you should use `client.on('messageCreate')`

Answer (score 1):

As per the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageCreate):

```js
//discord.js V12
-client.on('message', (msg) => {
//discord.js V13
+client.on('messageCreate', (msg) => {
```